# Advanced Customization of Alfresco

Tags: javascript, html, xml, content-management-system, alfresco

I am having trouble figuring out how to do even the simplest things in Alfresco, like typing a simple document. I've been Googling and noticed that customizations can be done through HTML documents. I need help and decided to post a question to a knowledgeable user platform. THe following customizations I would like are WAY far fetched and most likely not even achievable, but any help that can be provided I would really appreciate.

*list items in bold are most important

1. Anyone could be assigned a login and when they logged in they would have access to and easily view all of the contents of the site (or multiple sites that make up one accessible website?)
2. All of the items on the website would be a hierarchy, the user facing contents of the site would be a list of links with thumbnails, when one link was clicked it would be another list of links with large thumbnails, when one of those links was clicked a text document would be brought up, that document would contain clickable sections, when one of those sections was clicked it would bring up a page only containing the section clicked:

   - Links (crafts)
   - 2nd layer of links (modules)
   - Text and image document with clickable links (single module containing clickable sections)
   - Section (single sections of module)
3. **The module and section text would also contain images and tables throughout and mixed in the text**
4. **If a link (module or section) was used in multiple places all instances of the link would be linked to each other. If on instance was edited, the other would also change. THis setting could be turned off for any individual link if necessary.**
5. **Every document should have an easy to use live commenting system (something simple like Disqus would work) The comments are the most important on the single section pages but would also be good on the module page**
6. An advanced tagging system that would be part of the entire site/website environment. A user could type anything they wanted as a tag and use multiple tags. The tags would be used for their comments on the content (text, sections) but the tags could be searched (most importantly by the administrators of the site) at any time in the whole environment. A popularity of any tag could also be viewed (I'm not sure how that would work, possibly another section of the site or an easy to see column on any text/image document?)
7. A user could edit their own comment if they wished but would not be able to delete it entirely. Comments would also be date and time stamped.

I know all of this is most likely impossible but if anyone has an idea of Alfresco customizations that could pull any of this off, or of an entirely different secure platform or site that would perform anything similar to this please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a Web Content Management (WCM) System. Alfresco is a Document Management (DM) System. You can use Alfresco as a back-end for a custom content-centric solution, but if you are expecting to install it, start it up, and have anything close to what you've listed above, you are barking up the wrong tree.

Everything you've listed is a front-end concern. You can use whatever you want to develop that functionality, but none of it will leverage Alfresco unless you choose to store some of the data in the Alfresco back-end.

You might be better off looking at something in the WCM space, such as Drupal or Wordpress. Or if you want something Java-based, look at Magnolia CMS or Hippo CMS.

Comment: Thank you Jeff! I will definitely look into those and knowing that it's a WCM System for front-end that I need is very helpful.